# How to pass control name in user defined function using jQuery 

Tags: jquery

I have two controls in a form, day of month and month. Whenever the user changes the month I want it to change the number of days in the "day of month" combo box depending on the month. I want to write a user defined function as I have the same logic on many different pages.
Does anyone have any ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

on page load you can do the below

```
ddl1.attribute.add("onchange", string.Format("functionName('{0}')", ddl2.ClientId););
```

Comment: The above code adds an onchange event on the first combo, which is the month. we need to pass the client id of the second combo to the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function rebuildDaysOfMonthControl(controlId, month)
{
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var days = daysInMonth(month, currentYear);

    $(controlId).empty();

    //rebuild the days of month control
    for (var x = 1; x <= days; x++) {
        $(controlId).append(
            $('<option></option>').val(x).html(x)
        );
    }
}

$(function () {

    $('#monthControlId').live('change', function () {
        var selectedMonth = $(this).val();

        rebuildDaysOfMonthControl('#daysOfMonthControlId', selectedMonth);

    });

});
```